# Resolution friendly website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I have tried everything and failed. My current WordPress theme is not so mobile friendly, in fact, even at 768x1024 resolution it goes all crazy. I have only adjusted the content width, and sidebar width.

It is perfect at most of the screens, but if I try to view it on other devices, such as iPad, Kindle, it doesn't look right.

Screenfly iPad view: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//tryonlineroulette.com/&w=768&h=1024&a=22

Live website demo: http://tryonlineroulette.com

And here is the code that is responsible for mobile or different resolution view:

```
/***** Media Queries *****/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .mh-container { width: 980px; }
    #main-content { width: 630px; }
    .main-nav { width: 100%; }
    .loop-header, .loop-thumb { width: 100%; float: none; margin-right: 0; }
    .loop-thumb, .loop-header .entry-meta { margin-top: 20px; }
    .entry-title-wrap, .entry-meta-wrap { float: none; width: 100%; }
    .entry-title-wrap { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; }
    .entry-header .entry-meta { float: left; }
    .commentlist ul, .commentlist ol { margin: 0 0 30px 0; margin: 0 0 1.875rem 0; }
    .commentlist ul ul, .commentlist ol ol { margin: 0; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .mh-container { max-width: 440px; width: 90%; }
    #main-content, #main-sidebar { float: none; width: 100%; margin-right: 0; }
    #main-content { margin-bottom: 30px; margin-bottom: 1.875rem; }
    [class*='mh-col-'] { float: none; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
    .js .slicknav_menu { display: block; }
    .js .main-nav { display: none; }
    .header-wrap { padding: 0; }
    .logo { padding: 40px 0; padding: 2.5rem 0; }
    .latest-news-widget .news-item { margin-bottom: 30px !important; margin-bottom: 1.875rem !important; }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Here is what it should look like on the iPads, Kindles, Nexuses: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//tryonlineroulette.com/&w=1024&h=600&a=1

Comment: In order to make it responsive you should use percentages together with media queries. I look at your CSS and you are using pixels for the width of the elements. That's the reason why your site is not responsive (you should use %).

Comment: But can you please point out where should I use the '%' - ? I have already tried it before, with no luck.

I mean it looks perfect on all other resolutions:
1024 x 600
12" Netbook
1024 x 768
13" Notebook
1280 x 800
15" Notebook
1366 x 768
19" Desktop
1440 x 900
20" Desktop
1600 x 900
22" Desktop
1680 x 1050
23" Desktop
1920 x 1080
24" Desktop
1920 x 1200
1903 x 979

Comment: The elements with id "main-content" and "main-sidebar" should be using percentages in order to be responsive.

Comment: @wazaaaap OK, I've just tried it, and it didn't changed a thing, when viewing on the website on the device. Didn't work.

Comment: There might be some other problems. If you are beginner and trying to edit some theme it would be hard to get it right. I suggest you find some similar responsive wordpress theme.

Comment: BUMP any help would be great :(